# ObservedObject class function not being called when protocol fires

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, google-ima

While implementing the Google Interactive Media Ads (IMA) SDK protocols, my mediaPlayer/audioManager, which is an AVPlayer object, is not pausing during the adsManagerDidRequestContentPause delegate method. My mediaPlayer conforms to ObservableObject, which is where I think the problem is coming from but i'm not 100% positive.

When I press the play button, I play the audio and request the ads from my adsManager class. The issue is the preroll video plays but the audio from the content player plays over the preroll. The audio from the content player is supposed to pause when the preroll is playing and resume after it finishes. As you'll see in the code, AudioManager is also a singleton class.

Here's the code for when a user presses play.

```
@ObservedObject var manager = AudioManager.sharedInstance

func didTapPlayButton(){
    isPlaying.toggle()
    if isPlaying {
        audioManager.playLiveStream(with: pageInfo.tritonMount)
        adManager.requestAds()
    } else {
        audioManager.pause()
    }
}
```

And here's the adManager class with the Google IMA delegate methods. After setting breakpoints at each delegate method, I found that each call to audioManager is being called successfully, however, the audio from the audioManager doesn't actually pause.

```
@ObservedObject var manager = AudioManager.sharedInstance

func setUpContentPlayer() {
    contentPlayhead = IMAAVPlayerContentPlayhead(avPlayer: player)
    // Create a player layer for the player.
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer!.frame = videoView.underlyingView.layer.bounds
    videoView.underlyingView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
}

func setUpAdsLoader() {
    adsLoader = IMAAdsLoader(settings: nil)
    adsLoader!.delegate = self
}

func requestAds() {
    // Create an ad display container for ad rendering.
    let adDisplayContainer = IMAAdDisplayContainer(adContainer: videoView.underlyingView, companionSlots: nil)

    // Create an ad request with our ad tag, display container, and optional user context.
    let request = IMAAdsRequest(
        adTagUrl: kLivePrerollVastTag,
        adDisplayContainer: adDisplayContainer,
        contentPlayhead: contentPlayhead,
        userContext: nil)

    adsLoader!.requestAds(with: request)
}

func adsLoader(_ loader: IMAAdsLoader!, adsLoadedWith adsLoadedData: IMAAdsLoadedData!) {
    // Grab the instance of the IMAAdsManager and set ourselves as the delegate
    adsManager = adsLoadedData.adsManager
    adsManager!.delegate = self

    // Create ads rendering settings and tell the SDK to use the in-app browser.
    let adsRenderingSettings = IMAAdsRenderingSettings()

    adsRenderingSettings.webOpenerPresentingController = viewController

    // Initialize the ads manager.
    adsManager!.initialize(with: adsRenderingSettings)
}

//Ads Manager recieved ad request and is loading and starting ad
func adsManager(_ adsManager: IMAAdsManager!, didReceive event: IMAAdEvent!) {
    if (event.type == IMAAdEventType.LOADED) {
        // When the SDK notifies us that ads have been loaded, play them.
        adsManager.start()
    }
}

//Ads manager failed to receive ad request
func adsLoader(_ loader: IMAAdsLoader!, failedWith adErrorData: IMAAdLoadingErrorData!) {
    print("Error loading ads: \(String(describing: adErrorData.adError.message))")
    audioManager.resume()
}

func adsManager(_ adsManager: IMAAdsManager!, didReceive error: IMAAdError!) {
    // Something went wrong with the ads manager after ads were loaded. Log the
    // error and play the content.
    NSLog("AdsManager error: \(String(describing: error.message))")
    audioManager.resume()
}

/*Ads manager received request, initiated avplayer and is now
requesting player be paused in order or the Ads manager to play preroll*/
func adsManagerDidRequestContentPause(_ adsManager: IMAAdsManager!) {
    // The SDK is going to play ads, so pause the content.
    audioManager.pause()
}
/*Ads manager received request, played the preroll and is now
 requesting avplayer to resume live stream*/
func adsManagerDidRequestContentResume(_ adsManager: IMAAdsManager!) {
    // The SDK is done playing ads (at least for now), so resume the content.
    audioManager.resume()
}
```

AudioManagerClass:

```
    /// Upon setting this property any observers for 'currentItem' as well as any time observers will
/// be removed from the old value where applicable and added to the new value where applicable.
var player: AVPlayer? {
    didSet {
        oldValue?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem", context: &AudioManager.ObserveAVPlayerCurrentItem)
        oldValue?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", context: &AudioManager.ObserveAVPlayerRate)
        guard let player = self.player else { return }

        player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem", options: [.initial, .new], context: &AudioManager.ObserveAVPlayerCurrentItem)
        player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: [.initial, .new], context: &AudioManager.ObserveAVPlayerRate)
        player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
        if let tmpObs = timeObserver {
            print("Already have timeobserver, removing it")
            oldValue?.removeTimeObserver(tmpObs)
            timeObserver = nil
        }

        timeObserver = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1,preferredTimescale: 1),
            queue: nil,
            using: timeObserverCallback) as AnyObject?
    }

}
```

Comment: can you also share your AudioManager class

Comment: My AudioManager Class is big but here's the player part. I'm using KVO. Playing the item when the Current Item's status is "readyToPlay". I have a pause function that is player?.pause(). That pause function is the function being called on the IMA protocol but its not actually pausing the audio.